# Is it possible to customize the header column to expand button in antd table?

Tags: antd

I know how to expand and collapse rows in the antd Table. I know how to expand all or collapse all, as long as that button is outside of the table itself. What I don't know is how to put that functionality into the header of the table. Ie where that green highlight is, I would like my "expand all" button to be. I don't see it built in, and I don't see how to modify that column header.

[image: Expand column header location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible but it requires you having to utilize an external state to track expanded keys, as well as building your own expandable column. You also have to hide their expandable column if you don't want "duplicate" expansion control columns. In addition, you lose their animation on their expand icon, which you'd have to build yourself if you want to mimic their behavior. Here's a minimum viable example.

```js
const MyCustomTable = ({expandable, columns, dataSource, ...rest}) => {
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);

  const allAvailableKeys = dataSource.map(e => e.key)
  const processedColumns = [...columns]
  processedColumns.unshift({
    title: allAvailableKeys.every(e => expandedKeys.includes(e)) ? (
      <MinusSquareOutlined onClick={() => collapseAll()} />
    ) : (
      <PlusSquareOutlined onClick={() => expandAll()} />
    ),
    key: "expand",
    render: (_, record) => expandedKeys.includes(record.key) ? (
      <MinusSquareOutlined onClick={() => toggleExpandedKeys(record.key)} />
    ) : (
      <PlusSquareOutlined onClick={() => toggleExpandedKeys(record.key)}/>
    )
  });

  const toggleExpandedKeys = key => {
    setExpandedKeys(prev => {
      const outArr = [...prev];
      if (outArr.includes(key)) {
        return outArr.filter(e => e !== key);
      } else {
        outArr.push(key);
        return outArr;
      }
    })
  }

  const expandAll = () => {
    setExpandedKeys(allAvailableKeys)
  }

  const collapseAll = () => {
    setExpandedKeys([])
  }

  return (
    <Table
      columns={processedColumns}
      dataSource={dataSource}
      expandable={{
        ...expandable,
        expandedRowKeys: expandedKeys,
        expandIconColumnIndex: -1
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

See it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/expandable-row-antd4112-forked-o544t?file=/index.js)

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me that I can hide their column and build my own on top of that. Just that concept clears everything up! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use `::after` in CSS to add a heading there,
just select the tile class and add the header you want to it.

```
th.ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell::after {
content: "Password Changes";
}
```

"th" in the begining is because all expandable cells have that class, but none of them are a "th" tag except for the header.

result would be like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykDHX.png]

Comment: .ant-table-thead .ant-table-cell.ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell::after {
      content: "Version";
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-left: 4px; 
    }

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on ScratchNPurr's answer, I have created a custom ExpandButton component that renders the original html element from the built-in table expand button:

```js
interface ExpandButtonProps {
    expanded: boolean,
    onClick?(value: any): void
}

export const ExpandButton = (props: ExpandButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <button 
            type="button" 
            className={`ant-table-row-expand-icon ant-table-row-expand-icon-${props.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'}`} 
            aria-label="Expand row" 
            aria-expanded={props.expanded} 
            onClick={props.onClick} />
    )
}
```

and now my custom table column looks like this:

```js
{
  title: <ExpandButton expanded={state.expandedKeys?.length > 0} onClick={() => {}} />,
  key: "expand",
  render: (_, record) => <ExpandButton expanded={state.expandedKeys?.includes(record.key)} onClick={() => {}} />
},
```